# Large database needed for Solr Index speed test

Tags: sql-server, solr, indexing

I want to make a large SQL Server database to compare the indexing speed of Full Text search and Solr. How can I do it?

Do you have any comparison results or other suggestions?

Comment: Did you complete this experiment? I would like to see the results of the benchmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use wikipedia data dumps, or you could use stackoverflow data dumps.

I would use stackoverflow data dumps, since wikipedia dumps are HUGE.
I think wikipedia also has partial dumps, for development and experimentation, which probably would be more suitable.

Wikipedia is MySQL, Stackoverflow SQL-Server.

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump

http://media10.simplex.tv/content/xtendx/stu/stackoverflow/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99999999; i++) {
    SolrDocument sd = new SolrDocument();
    sd.put("id", i);
    sd.put("somefield", someRandomValue());
    // etc
    solrServer.index(sd);
}
```